# Matching game using javascript

Tags: javascript

I making a game the logic of the game is to match the word given but it uses a image.

How to validate it using image?

```js
< script >
  var e = document.getElementById("E");
var n = document.getElementById("N");
var d = document.getElementById("D");
/*move img_letter*/
//E
function move_E() {
  e.onclick = function() {
    e.style.bottom = "300px"
    e.style.left = "320px"
  }
};
//N
function move_N() {
  n.onclick = function() {
    n.style.bottom = "300px"
    n.style.left = "550px"
  }
};
//D
function move_D() {
  d.onclick = function() {
    d.style.bottom = "300px"
    d.style.left = "780px"
  }
};
window.onload = function() {
  move_E();
  move_N();
  move_D();
}

< /script>
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>
<style>
  #D {
    margin-left: -3%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #N {
    margin-left: 5%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  #E {
    margin-left: 13%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  .img_letter {
    margin-top: 25%;
    margin-left: 40%;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <h1 align="center">END</h1>
  <div class="img_letter">
    <div id="N">
      <img src="http://i62.tinypic.com/2rx8qjb_th.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="E">
      <img src="http://i61.tinypic.com/2qny5xx_th.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div id="D">
      <img src="http://i57.tinypic.com/2554dfk_th.png" width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</htmL>
```

Comment: Syntax error at `</htmL>` ? Try substituting lowercase  `l` for uppercase `L` to render valid closing `html` tag : `</html>`

Comment: It is unclear to me what the problem is. What do you mean when you say "validate it using image"? Using the images `id` in your code (as you have already started to do) is enough to build the logic of your game.

Comment: thx for the answer this i want to be out put http://i57.tinypic.com/xm0bhl_th.jpg

Comment: @1cgonza thx for the answering the game that i want is to be like this  i57.tinypic.com/xm0bhl_th.jpg